# mysql - php . How to find

Tags: mysql

i have 2 table

```
users : id , name
order : id , price, user_id
```

a users have more than one order. And i want to select a users

who have total price >100 . how to do ?

EX : user John have 3 orders  with price : 30$, 40$ , 50$

```
SELECT * FROM user u 
INNER JOIN order o ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE sum(o.price) >100
```

this query will get the user is john ? 30+40+50  = 110 >100
?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not allowed to use aggregate functions (i.e. `SUM`) in your `WHERE` clause. They should be used in the `HAVING` clause. To compute aggregates you need to `GROUP BY` something, in your case by `u.id`.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
INNER JOIN order o ON u.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING sum(o.price) > 100
```

Note that if you would need users with no order you would have to use `LEFT JOIN`!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.Id, Sum(o.price) FROM user u 
INNER JOIN order o ON o.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.Id
HAVING sum(o.price) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all answer but i catch problem
now i have a new table order_file

```
users      : id , name
order      : id , price, user_id
order_file : id , file , order_id
```

users, order is one-many

order , order_file is one-many

a user John have 1 order with price is 200$
and this order link to order_file with two record

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
INNER JOIN order o ON u.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN order_file of ON of.order_id = o.id
WHERE u.name = 'John'
```

we will get two rows.Only diff value in order_file

now to get once i use DISTINCT , and i get 1 row

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM user u
INNER JOIN order o ON u.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN order_file of ON of.order_id = o.id
WHERE u.name = 'John'
```

then i do SUM , oh la la , i get 400$ , not 200$

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, sum(o.price)
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN order o ON u.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN order_file of ON of.order_id = o.id
    WHERE u.name = 'John'
```

how to i can get extracty 200$ , not duplicate row :(

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question. And if the existing answers are good, you should accept one of them.